# Windows Vista on AWS

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, windows-vista

I've only found details about running Windows Server on AWS, is it possible to create my own Windows Vista VMWare instance locally and upload the image to AWS?

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: Good question, we have a distributed team that sometimes travel and want to experiment shared Windows machines on AWS. Saves time to setup and we can access it 24/7.

Running VMWare locally takes up too much resources.

Answer (score 1):

EC2 does have a [facility for importing VMs](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/vmimport/). Licensing is up to you of course, but that's manageable.